# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS boots twice every time, first in low graphics then in high graphics

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, integrated-graphics, lubuntu

Recently installed Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, works fine but it boots twice every time. First in low res mode, then after a few seconds, the screen becomes black for about 3-4 mins, then it finally boots to high res.

How can I make it boot to high res right away?

Comment: You may be using the term "boot" in a way that might confuse readers.  I assume you aren't referring to the system actually rebooting.  It sounds like you're describing the system booting into the LXDE desktop in low res, then the display winks out while it changes to the normal resolution.  If so, that resolution change normally happens very early in the boot process, and then the Desktop Environment uses those settings.  It sounds like it may be an issue with Lubuntu's implementation of LXDE, and an issue is occurring after the DE is loaded.  (cont'd)

Comment: With Lubuntu, does the boot process display detail long enough that you can see process messages change from low res to normal res text (usually happens within the first few seconds)?  Let me suggest a diagnostic, although if it works, you may just want to make the change.  [LXLE](http://www.lxle.net/about/) is a Lubuntu spin that has some additional refinement.  It's current version is based on the previous Lubuntu LTS release, so it will also be a little more stable.  Try that just to see if the screen issue goes away.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it doesn't, it could mean that something like the window manager that LXDE uses may not like your graphics hardware.  In that case, either try a different DE, or go into problem-solving mode if you have some Linux proficiency.  If it does solve the problem, it could just be a bug or compatibility issue with the current Lubuntu release.